# Regular expressions that do not contain consecutive newline characters

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to allow input of characters that do not contain a leading newline and consecutive newlines in Angular (Typescript).

OK

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

NG

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

NG

```
aaaa
bbbb

cccc
```

We were able to create a regular expression that allows the input of characters that do not contain a leading newline.

```
^(?!\n)[a-z\n]+$
```

How can I create a regular expression that works "without consecutive line breaks"?
I have created such a regular expression, but it does not work.

```
/^(?!\n)(?!.*\n{2,})[a-z\n]+$/
```

Comment: You can omit multiline and the `\n` in the character class `^[a-z]+(?:\n[a-z]+)*$`  https://regex101.com/r/NnqGwB/1

Comment: You can try this regex: `^(?:.+[\r\n])+$` without `MULTILINE` mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is

```js
^[a-z]+(?:\n[a-z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxCcHi/1/).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:\n[a-z]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\n` - an LF char
  - `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

To allow CRLF and LF line break sequences, prepend the `\n` with an optional CR (carriage return) pattern, `\r?`:

```js
^[a-z]+(?:\r?\n[a-z]+)*$
```